# Error in my math formula for implementing CUSUM in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to implement a check for decreasing values of avg temperatures to see when the temperature starts falling. See the chart of temperatures here:

[image]

Here is the formula I'm trying to implement:

[image]

Here is my code to implement that formula:

```
temps <- read.delim("temps.txt")
date_avgs <- rowMeans(temps[2:length(temps)], dims=1, na.rm=T)
mu <- 87
threshold <- 86
constant <- 3

date_avgs
S <- 0 * date_avgs
for (i in 2:length(date_avgs)) {
  value <- S[i-1] + (mu - date_avgs[i] - constant)
  cat("\nvalue", value, "si", date_avgs[i], i)
  S[i] <- max(0, value)
  if(S[i] >= threshold){
    #Once I hit this for the first time, that indicates at this index the temp is decreasing
    cat("\nDecreased past my threshold!!!", S[i] ,i)
  }
}
```

But I'm not able to detect the change as I expect. My formula doesn't get over the threshold until index 108, when it should get there around index 60.

Here is the plot of my S (or CUSUM) values:

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong in my formula?

Comment: Is `temps` a vector? `rowMeans` need an array of at least 2 dimensions. You don't need `c()` in `temps[c(2:length(temps))]`. Finally, in `value <- S[i-1] + (mu - date_avgs[i] - constant)` you should start `for (i in 2:length(date_avgs))` .

Comment: You start by asking for a binary result,  "is S(t) > T ?"   and then show us a graph of numeric values.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: When `i == 1`, the value of `S[i-1]` is not defined, R's indices are 1-based.

Comment: Updated my code according to your comments. Still not working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is `mu <- mean(date_avgs)` basically means of all the observations. But `mu` should be "mean of X **if no change"**. Thus mu should be about 87 but according your code and plotted data seems to be 80 or less.

```
# simulated data
set.seed(4422)
date_avgs <- c(runif(60, 84, 92), 88-(1:50)-rnorm(50,0,4))
plot(date_avgs)
# setting constants
mu <- 87
threshold <- 86
constant <- 3
```

[image: Simulated data]

```
# after running for cycle
Index <- match(S[S >= threshold][1], S) 
Index
[1] 75
# for data
> date_avgs[74]
[1] 73.41981

# Considering a lower threshold 
# (as maximum allowable difference to detect trend 2 * C)
mu <- 87
threshold <- 6 # arbitrary 
constant <- 3
# after running for cycle
Index <- match(S[S >= threshold][1], S) 
Index
[1] 66
```

So I think code is fine, maybe the interpretation is not

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried manually setting mu to 87, but I'm still not triggering the change detection until index 97. So I still must be missing something.

Comment: OK, but are you sure it has to be around 60? Because you need that xt < mu - C in order to start getting S[t] > 0. This would occours at xt < 84 = 87 - 3, that seems to be date_avegs indexed greater than 70 (form your plot). But additionally you require that S(t) > T = 86, that means S[t] should accumulate more differences (mu - C) - xt, which are initially lower. I understand that differences (mu-C) - xt accumulate, therefore the threshold should be taken as a maximum allowable difference. Why T = 86?

Comment: Marcelo, you are right, my code was fine. I just had to tweak my mu, c and threshold values. Thanks for the help!